# Link thumbs from different page to Flexslider with hashTags in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider, hashtag

I am loading all the Thumb images attached to a post in wordpress.

http://www.piagrimbuehler.ch/wordpress/skill/food/

When I click on a Thumb the Project page opens and the images are being displayed in a flexslider.
But I want the flexslider display the thumb I clicked.

I am trying to make it work with HashTags. I already made the URL with the Image ID.

http://www.piagrimbuehler.ch/wordpress/projects/waldhaus-kuche/#125   Like this.

But now the flexslider should display the right image.
Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

This is my flexslider script:

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        slideshowSpeed: 6000,  
        directionNav: true,
        slideshow: 1, 
        controlsContainer: '.slideshow',                        
        animation: 'fade',
        touch: true,
        controlNav: false
    });
```

And I found this script:

```
(jQuery.noConflict())(function($) {
    //Get your hash tag
    var loc = $(location).attr('href');
    var idx = 1;
    if(loc.lastIndexOf('#') != -1)
    {
        idx = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('#')+1).replace('slide', '');
    }

    //verify that idx is really a number
    if(isNaN(idx-0))
    {
        idx = 1;
    }

    $('#yourFlexSlider').flexslider ({
        startAt: idx
    });
});
```

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem :-)

Needed to change my href.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#slide<?php echo $i; $i++;?>" ><?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumb' ); ?>
```

But my only problem now is that the **next** and **prev** button don't work.
The "controlNav" works.
If I click directly on the **next** and **prev** the next image doesn't appear.
But if I first click on the "controlNav" and then the prev or next it all works.

[The link to see it](http://www.piagrimbuehler.ch/wordpress/skill/food/)